# Vue strap datepicker is not trigger @change method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using vue-strap for my datepicker

```
<label for='to' v-text="'Date to'"></label>
<div class="input-group calendar">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
  <div class="datepicker-wrapper">
    <vue-datepicker
       @change='getData'
       id='to'
       v-model='dateTo'
       :format="'MM/dd/yyyy'"
       class='react-datepicker__input-container'
     ></vue-datepicker>
   </div>
 </div>
```

**Data:**

```
data () {
  return {
    dateFrom: '',
    dateTo: ''
  }
},
```

**Methods:**

```
mounted () {
  this.getData()
},
methods: {
  setDate (numOfDays) {
    return moment().subtract(numOfDays, 'days').format('L')
  },
  getData () {
    if (!this.dateFrom && !this.dateTo) {
      this.dateFrom = this.setDate(2).toString()
      this.dateTo = this.setDate(0).toString()
    }
    axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: this.$store.state.endpoints.baseUrl + '/foo/?date_from=' + this.dateFrom + '&date_to=' + this.dateTo,
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {}
  })
}
```

}

So, there are 2 datepickers, 1st is displaying current date - 2 days, 2nd just current date. When i change date it is changing, but axios is not sending request. There is a **warning** in console:

> [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "value"

I do not understand what shud i change to make it work.

Comment: can you add what npm package provides `vue-datepicker` component from example?

Comment: https://yuche.github.io/vue-strap/#datepicker
vue strap datepicker

Comment: check [Vue-strap](https://yuche.github.io/vue-strap/#getting-started), **vue-strap** is vuejs (1.0X) based. but you tagged vuejs2, so i think above warning was threw out due to you used vuejs2 (Vuejs2 doesn't recommend direct-change the value for one prop) instead of vuejs (1.0x). Then vue-strap datepicker will not emit one `change` event, so the method **getData** will never be executed. as above link you provied, try `:value.sync="dateTo"`, then use one watch to detect `dateTo`.

Comment: @Sphinx you are right, thanks. I changed to another datepicker for vuejs2.